# Converting .exe to VS solution file / project

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler

I've recently had an issue at work where I have lost my solution files to my projects, but I still have the executables that have been produced by the projects / solution.  It has been collection of 50+ webforms.

I have tried some de-compiler tools like ILSpy, JustComplie and .Net Reflector but everything gives source code in different format (not originally written by me) and also not designs of forms.

Is there any possibility to decompiling the executable back into a solution/project file?

Comment: What language were they originally written in?
Do you have the intellectual rights to the source code?

Comment: It was developed by me, using VB.Net as code behind. What do you mean by intellectual rights?

Comment: If I develop a product for a company, they normally own the intellectual property rights for it. It would actually be a copyright and contractual breach if I kept a copy or reproduced it, by, for example, decompiling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering .NET sources into full blown project](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8215/4202)

Comment: @Dragonthoughts , you are correct. Even though this question is **almost three years old,** your comment **still** applies. Say, if I worked for Microsoft, helped produce an awesome application, but then got fired, or quit, and I kept the executable(s), but didn't get around to keeping (**more like _stealing_**) the solution files, it is technically illegal, unless you have gotten permission of your superiors, which, I find would be highly unlikely. Why would they let you keep the program, knowing that you could just decompile it right-off-the-bat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can actually decompile the executables to a solution structure as seen on VS. 
Although you can decompile the executable files (there are decompilers on the net that can perofrm the operation for you - only the decompilation),
you need to re-create the solution manually and add the source files you have retrieved from the previous operation. 
Furthermore, if your files were obfuscated this makes it harder for them to be decompiled.
Even if this works, be prepared to do some debugging and check references/dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Decompiler that works very well for .Net applications called DNSpy. 
Here is link to the Project : 
https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

After you have decompiled you can start debugging and such from this application.

Hope this help.